# Wrapping existing memory with a node::Buffer

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

What's the correct way to wrap existing memory with a node.js node::Buffer? I can't seem to get the free_callback to call with Buffer.

I know there was some chatter on IRC quite a while back on getting rid of this. We're on the 0.10.x series but can move if necessary...

```
void free_test_cb(char *m,void *hint) {
    DBG_OUT("FREEING MEMORY.");
    free(m);
}

Handle<Value> WrapMemBufferTest(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    char *mem = (char *) ::malloc(100);
    memset(mem,'A',100);
    node::Buffer *buf = node::Buffer::New(mem,100,free_test_cb,0);
    return scope.Close(buf->handle_);
}
```

But the `free_test_cb()` is just not getting called in a simple test program.
...and then I even tried throwing these in there:

```
void weak_cb(Persistent<Value> object, void* parameter) {
    object.Dispose();
}

Handle<Value> WrapMemBufferTest(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    char *mem = (char *) ::malloc(100);
    memset(mem,'A',100);
    node::Buffer *buf = node::Buffer::New(mem,100,free_test_cb,0);
    buf->handle_.MakeWeak(NULL, weak_cb);  // new
    return scope.Close(buf->handle_);
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `free` in C++?

Answer (score 0):

The callback is called on V8's GC, not when you delete the buffer in C++. Can you construct a loop where the buffer would be cleaned up by V8's GC?

Comment: Would you like to rephrase this, in order to reduce the impression that it is a comment asking for clarification, instead of being an actual answer?